# Saving blob to file

Tags: javascript, svg, blob

We currently have a very unefficient way of making businesscards.
A designer does them 1 by 1 in illustrator which is not efficient at all.

So my idea was to make 1 template in illustrator, export it as an svg and build a simple web tool where people can edit the svg and put the correct name, job title and phone number in themselves.

I managed to make a basic editor where I load in a svg version of our business card and then replace text like name and job title with data from input fields. But I cannot figure out how to save the blob holding the new svg file. I get it to open it in a new window (adress is something like blob:null/a0b8...).
But now i'm totally stuck getting the blob saved as a svg with the updated businesscard info.

I tried a lot of examples that I found with google, but my limited knoledge of this didnt help me making sence of examples.

Any ideas how I can do this? The only restriction I have is that I cannot use backend tools. It has to be in front end technology.

```js
function changeSVGdata() {
                var nameValue = document.getElementById("name").value;
                var phoneNumberValue = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;
                var nameElement = document.getElementsByClassName("cls-2");
                var phoneNumberElement = document.getElementsByClassName("cls-1")
                nameElement[0].textContent = nameValue;
                phoneNumberElement[0].textContent = phoneNumberValue;
            }  
            
            
            function saveNewCard() {
                var fileName = "Business Card - " + document.getElementById("name").value; + ".svg";
                var svg = document.getElementById("svg");
                var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
                var svg_blob = new Blob([serializer.serializeToString(svg)],{'type': "image/svg+xml"});
                var url = URL.createObjectURL(svg_blob);
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                var svg_win = window.open(url, "svg_win");
            }
```

```html
<h1>Business Card Generator</h1>
        Name: <input type="text" name="nameTag" id="name"><br>
        Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phonenr" id="phoneNumber"><br><br>
        <button onclick="changeSVGdata()">Make Business Card</button>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="svg">         
             <svg id="Business_Card" data-name="Business Card" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="85.71mm" height="55.71mm" viewBox="0 0 242.94 157.91">
            <defs>
            <style>
            .cls-1 {
            font-size: 14px;
            }

            .cls-1, .cls-2 {
            fill: #232323;
            font-family: ArialMT, Arial;
            }

            .cls-2 {
            font-size: 21px;
            }

            .cls-3 {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #232323;
            stroke-miterlimit: 10;
            stroke-width: 1px;
            }
            </style>
            </defs>
            <title>business card</title>
            <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(39 78.75)">0612345678</text>
            <text class="cls-2" transform="translate(38 52.75)">Donald Duck</text>
            <rect class="cls-3" x="1" y="1" width="240.94" height="155.91"/>
            </svg>  
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button onclick="saveNewCard()">Save Business Card</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use anchor's [download](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) attribute, change your button to this:

Notice I moved the onclick to the anchor and added a new parameter to your function, `this` is the current element (`<a>`), we send it as parameter to saveNewCard function.

```
<a href="" onclick="saveNewCard(this)">
    <button>Save Business Card</button>
</a>
```

And your function to this:

```
function saveNewCard(anchor) {
//                   ^ anchor contains the reference to the <a> element
    var fileName = "Business Card - " + document.getElementById("name").value; + ".svg";
    var svg = document.getElementById("svg");
    var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    var svg_blob = new Blob([serializer.serializeToString(svg)],{'type': "image/svg+xml"});
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(svg_blob);

    anchor.href = url;
    anchor.download = fileName;
}
```

This will set the href to the blob url and the download attribute to your desired filename.

Concept demo: https://codepen.io/emed/pen/MOjqMM/?editors=1010

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get this to work. I assume the anchor.href here has to be implemented as self.href and self.download as that is the href you gave it in the button link. If I don't do that, I get an anchor undefined error in the console.  I send an alert after every step, so the fileName variable returns a nice string, the url variable shows me the adress of the blob and the self.href shows me the same adress as the url variable so that all is fine. but still if I click the button nothing is saved or download. No errors in the console just nothing happens.

Comment: I guess the problem is with how I call upon the anchor in javascript. In your example you named the anchor

<a href="#self" onclick="saveNewCard(this)">

But when I change it to href="#saveFunction"  I can't seem to connect to it in javascript.

when I use  saveFunction.href = url 
I get an unchaght referenceError: saveFunction is not defined.

So how do I need to  write this up to access the anchor?

Comment: and my last question:
In the onclick event you wrote:

onclick="saveNewCard(this)" 

what is the 'this' for? why did you put it in the function call? What does it send to the function?

Comment: @MichielVXL forget about `#self` it was just a placeholder. `this` is the current element in which the onclick was invoked, we send it to the funcion and capture it in a parameter called `anchor`, thats why I used `anchor.href`.